# How to I create a new column in a table and add values to it

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, alter-table

I have to create a new column in my table called Raise that has a 20% raise from the values of the SAL column, here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT ENAME,EMPNO, JOB, SAL from emp
ALTER TABLE emp
ADD Raise (INTEGER)
ALTER TABLE emp
Raise=SAL+SAL*0.20
```

Im not too sure what Im doing wrong here

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Oracle (because your table looks like `EMP` from the `SCOTT` schema), is this what you want?

```
alter table emp add raise number;
update emp set raise = sal * 1.2;
```

Note that if you want to increase something by 20%, then you probably want the result to be numeric rather than integer.

Comment: didn't know there was a schema named after me

Comment: @urdearboy: :) - actually it's named after Bruce Scott, one of the original designers of the Oracle database...

Comment: Thanks GMB, as someone new to SQL your help was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If this is just for a ADHOC query, then

```
SELECT
    ename,
    empno, 
    job,
    sal,
    (sal * 1.2) raise
FROM emp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a virtual column to automatically populate raise each time

`alter table emp add raise number generated always as (sal*1.2) virtual;`